# DefaultTraceListener doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to use the Debug and Trace classes with DefaultTraceListener. My messages appears normally in the Output window only when I start my application in Debug mode.

My question now, how can I get my messages in the output window when I run my application without debugging?

here is how I setup the Listener

```
DefaultTraceListener defaultListener = new DefaultTraceListener();
Debug.Listeners.Add(defaultListener);
```

Comment: You are asking for teleportation as a feature.  SysInternals' DebugView can provide it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't see anything in the output window of visual studio unless you have the debugger attached. You could run debugview to view the output of Debug statements in your code. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx

Comment: and how can I run it?

Comment: Sorry I updated my answer above. Basically debugview is an exe you download and run on your machine. It's sole purpose is to view debug statements from code that is being executed on the current machine.

Comment: how i can filter the output to get only messages from my application?

Comment: Another tool is at the following url. It's pretty much the same app but it lists the name of the process that created the debug statement. http://tracespy.codeplex.com/